# Removing JavaFX Accordion Border

Tags: javafx, border, accordion

I'm working on a project and am theming a JavaFX application with CSS as I go. I'm having trouble removing the border around the Content of a JavaFX TitledPane in an Accordion. There appears to be 1px line at the bottom that I cannot seem to remove (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiINc.png).

Has anyone faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
accordion.setStyle("-fx-box-border: transparent;");
```

Reasoning behind why this works is explained in the answer to the similar question:

- [How do I get rid of the border around a split pane in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856359/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-border-around-a-split-pane-in-javafx)

Comment: easy and work like a charm.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.titled-pane > *.content {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: This removes the border from TitledPane's inside the Accordion, not from the accordion itself