# How to get rid of border in SplitPane (JavaFX) ?

Tags: javafx, split, border, fxml, splitpane

I'd like to remove a border inside a splitPane but i can't figure out from where this border comes.

[SplitPane Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ib5B.png)

In the picture we can see in red the splitpane border, in blue the two components borders and in green the divider border. But between the red and blue border, there is this little white part and this is the part i'd like to remove.

Here is a more precise picture of why it bother me:

[Focus on borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYC9Y.png)

The red border is still the splitPane border, there is again this white part and then one of my splitPane's child.

FXML is really simple so i'll post it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

    <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@transparentDivider.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3083623693379791" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="578.0" style="-fx-border-color: red; -fx-box-border:: transparent;">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: blue;" />
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: blue;" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

CSS i'm using for the test:

```
.split-pane:horizontal > .split-pane-divider {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-border-color: green;
}
```

Comment: http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get rid of the border around a split pane in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856359/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-border-around-a-split-pane-in-javafx)